# Angular 4 Semantic UI Tabs only work after refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, semantic-ui

I have some semantic UI tabs set up in my component's template.html like this:

```
<div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
    <a class="item active" data-tab="global" >Global</a>
    <a class="item" data-tab="gen_config" >Config</a>
    <a class="item" data-tab="service" >Service</a>
    <a class="item" data-tab="change" >Change</a>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment active" data-tab="global"> //some stuff// </div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment active" data-tab="gen_config"> //some stuff// </div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment active" data-tab="service"> //some stuff// </div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment active" data-tab="change"> //some stuff// </div>
```

I instantiated the tabs in a custom JS file which is being loaded through the index.html page and contains this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
    $('.top.menu .item').tab();
    $('.tabular.menu .item').tab();
});
```

Whenever I route to the component that contains those tabs, the tabs do not work. However, **whenever I refresh the page while on that component, the tabs start working**. Is there a reason why this is happening?

My biggest concern is as to why the tabs do not work after routing to the component, but only work after refreshing the page after routing.

I've tried to implement a setTimeout in my components onInit method, as well as load the tabs in the ngAfterViewInit and ngOnInit methods as well but to no avail.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$( document ).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) runs only once, when your web page is opened/refreshed. Quoting the official documentation:

> Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Angular Applications are [Single Page Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). This means that when you use the Angular Router to change components within an application, the page is not refreshed, only the content is changed, dynamically.

The behavior you are seeing is because you initially open your app to its default page, the `$(document).ready()` function is called, but at this point in time, your semantic elements are not in the DOM. The `ready()` function executes, fails to find your elements, and hence doesn't initialize them with the settings. When you route to your component, `$(document).ready()` is not called again, since the page is not refreshed. Only the content inside the `<router-outlet>` directive is changed. So in essence, your semantic elements are added to the DOM BUT since `$(document).ready()` will NOT execute, they are not initialized with the required behavior. When you refresh the page while on the routed component however, `$(document).ready()` **IS** called and this time the elements **ARE** in the DOM (because when Angular initializes, it determines which component you are on based on the URL), which is why the initialization code targets them properly and you see the behavior as expected.

To circumvent this issue, I would recommend moving your initialization code inside the `ngOnInit` function.

```
export class RoutedComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
        $('.top.menu .item').tab();
        $('.tabular.menu .item').tab();
    }
}
```

This way, whenever your route to your component, your initialization code will be executed. `ngOnInit` is a [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) that will be called every time your component is instantiated.